# Convert comma separated string into rows

Tags: sql, split

I have a comma separated string.

Now I'd like to separate this string value into each row.

Input:

`1,2,3,4,5`

Required output:

```
   value
----------
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
```

How can I achieve this in sql?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.  This is highly database specific.

Comment: MSSQL, MySQL...?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `STRING_SPLIT` function if you are on SQL Server

```
SELECT value
FROM STRING_SPLIT('1,2,3,4,5', ',')
```

Else you can loop on the `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function and insert every string in a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres, you can use string_to_array and unnest:

```
select *
from unnest(string_to_array('1,2,3,4,5',',') as t(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can also use the 'regexp_split_to_table()' function.

If you're using MariaDB or MySQL you can use a recursive CTE such as:

```
with recursive itemtable as (
        select
            trim(substring_index(data, ',', 1)) as value,
            right(data, length(data) - locate(',', data, 1)) as data
        from (select '1,2,3,4,5' as data) as input
        union
        select
            trim(substring_index(data, ',', 1)) as value,
            right(data, length(data) - locate(',', data, 1)) as data
        from itemtable
    )
```